# Parse log file by log line

Tags: c#, parsing, log4net

I'm using `log4net` and it occasionally writes an exception to the log file. Now I want to insert each log line, which can be more than 1 line (e.g. exceptions including stacktrace) long,  so

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(...)){}
```

would break up exceptions. Here's a sample log file:

```
2017-02-22 14:37:17,212 [Foo.Bar]  INFO  - This is something nice to log
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at Foo.Bar.<>c__DisplayClass282_0.<FooBar>b__0(DataRow row) in somefile.cs:line 2657
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Foo.Bar.<FooBar>d__282.MoveNext() in somefile.cs:line 2657
```

I want the very first line to be parsed in a string, as well as the whole remaining rest (in this example, the exception in general).

Any good ideas to get started?

Comment: I would start here: [ask]

Comment: @rory.ap thanks, I'm pretty fine. I just didn't have any point to get started with. Thank you by the way for downvoting without stating explicit reasons. Maybe you should be taking a look at the guide on how to properly review (in your book) 'stupid questions'. Why is stackoverflow so unfriendly?

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't bother to read the [help] and [ask] before posting your question.  Your question is too broad and shows no research effort.  It's not that SO is unfriendly; it's more that people are tired of the same types of questions being asked over and over without the person understanding the rules.

Comment: @rory.ap I didn't include anything such as research efforts due to the fact that I didn't have any point to get started with. Besides, in how far is this supposed to be 'too broad'? And more importantly, is it a rule that you NECESSARILY NEED TO HAVE BY ANY CHANCE a point or something you tried although the latter may be less than good in quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, using Regex to split the rows. However, this is assuming that all the log entries begin with a date in that format.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string RegexString = @"(?=\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}[,])";
    string Log4NetSample = Properties.Resources.Log4Net_Example;
    List<string> ParsedLogItems = new List<string>();
    foreach (var Item in Regex.Split(Log4NetSample, RegexString))
        if (Item.Trim() != string.Empty)
            ParsedLogItems.Add(Item);


    foreach (var Item in ParsedLogItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("===== New Log Item =====");
        Console.WriteLine(Item);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I used this text as a demo and I changed a few of the dates just to show that it would match multiple.

```
2017-02-22 14:37:17,212 [Foo.Bar]  INFO  - This is something nice to log
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at Foo.Bar.<>c__DisplayClass282_0.<FooBar>b__0(DataRow row) in somefile.cs:line 2657
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Foo.Bar.<FooBar>d__282.MoveNext() in somefile.cs:line 2657

2012-03-31 14:37:17,212 [Foo.Bar]  INFO  - This is something nice to log
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at Foo.Bar.<>c__DisplayClass282_0.<FooBar>b__0(DataRow row) in somefile.cs:line 2657
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Foo.Bar.<FooBar>d__282.MoveNext() in somefile.cs:line 2657

2018-08-14 14:37:17,212 [Foo.Bar]  INFO  - This is something nice to log
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at Foo.Bar.<>c__DisplayClass282_0.<FooBar>b__0(DataRow row) in somefile.cs:line 2657
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Foo.Bar.<FooBar>d__282.MoveNext() in somefile.cs:line 2657
```

And the code produces the following output:

```
===== New Log Item =====
2017-02-22 14:37:17,212 [Foo.Bar]  INFO  - This is something nice to log
    System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
       at Foo.Bar.<>c__DisplayClass282_0.<FooBar>b__0(DataRow row) in somefile.cs:line 2657
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at Foo.Bar.<FooBar>d__282.MoveNext() in somefile.cs:line 2657


===== New Log Item =====
2012-03-31 14:37:17,212 [Foo.Bar]  INFO  - This is something nice to log
    System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
       at Foo.Bar.<>c__DisplayClass282_0.<FooBar>b__0(DataRow row) in somefile.cs:line 2657
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at Foo.Bar.<FooBar>d__282.MoveNext() in somefile.cs:line 2657


===== New Log Item =====
2018-08-14 14:37:17,212 [Foo.Bar]  INFO  - This is something nice to log
    System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
       at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
       at Foo.Bar.<>c__DisplayClass282_0.<FooBar>b__0(DataRow row) in somefile.cs:line 2657
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at Foo.Bar.<FooBar>d__282.MoveNext() in somefile.cs:line 2657
```

Comment: Thank you. I configured log4net to start with the date, which lets your answer suit my needs! Thank you!